# HTML: перебор произвольных DOM-элементов клавишей Tab

Tags: html, css

Допустим, я хочу чтобы чтобы на любые DOM-элементы (например, на `<div>`ы указанного класса) можно было наводиться клавишей Tab, как это можно делать со ссылками и полями ввода. Соответственно, если таких элементов несколько, то при повторном нажатии на клавишу `tab` должен быть выделен следующий элемент.

Уже знаю, что что внешний вид предстоит выделенного объекта нужно будет прописать самому (так как таковой определён по умолчанию лишь для полей ввода и ссылок). Также предполагаю, что атрибут для полей, отвечающий за порядок их перебора клавишей Tab, использовать для других элементов нельзя.

Comment: Согласно спецификации tabindex может быть на любом элементе, просто поля ввода и ссылки не требуют его по умолчанию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div tabindex="0">
Первый див
</div>
<div tabindex="2">
Второй див
</div>
<div tabindex="1">
Третий див
</div>
</body>
</html>
```